# How can i use cfschedule in coldfusion 9 cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Does the cfscript equivalent for cfschedule even exist in coldfusion 9 ?
If it doesn't exist, is there an alternative way to run scheduled tasks from cfscript ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Adobe's documentation, the cfschedule tag is [not yet supported in cfscript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ec0). You would have to [write your own implementation](http://www.cutterscrossing.com/index.cfm/2009/10/8/Can-We-Extend-the-ColdFusion-Server) to utilize cfschedule within cfscript.

Comment: Make a custom function that is basically a wrapper to the CFSCHEDULE tag.  Then call that function within your CFSCRIPT.  Of course could expand on that idea and make a CFC that houses functions that are used for your scheduling needs and make calls to that within your CFSCRIPT

Comment: Yes, that's how i'm handling it now. made a Scheduler.cfc in cfml with a "schedule" function containing the cfschedule tag. The wrapper function passes all the arguments to the cfschedule tag. In cfscript calling new Scheduler().schedule(...).
Thanks anyway to confirm this work method.